# How can i refer to a span element in a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I have a question with SPAN elements in a FORM in javascript.
I'm studying 'form & validation' w/headfirst js book and 
there are some examples like below,:

-.html

```
<form name="orderform" ...>
...
<input id="zipcode" type="text" name="zipcode" onblur="validateZipcode(this, document.getElementById('zipcode_help'));" />
<span id="zipcode_help"></span>
....
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="placeOrder(this.form);" />
</form>
```

-.script

```
function validateZipcode(inputField, helpText) {
....
helpText.innerHTML = "Please enter a number";
....
}

function placeOrder(form) {
...
if (validateZipcode(form["zipcode"], form["zipcode_help"]) {
form.submit();
....
}
```

and here is my question.(It's not the same as the title I wrote, btw.:/)
How can a span element, be referred as "form["zipcode_help"] in the function placeOrder?
I know all form fields can be referred with its "name" property. 
and I thought a span element can't be like that because it doesn't belong to a form and haven't even got a name property.

---

I now have changed my question slightly.: How " document.getElementById("zipcode_help")" can be equal to "form["zipcode_help"]? The THING which is found by getElementById method is a SPAN, not a FORM FIELD. And, "zipcode_help" in "form[]" is an ID, not a NAME property, so it seems to me that it's even WRONG in grammar!

Answer (score 0):

Your span has an id, so use the [`document.getElementById()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById):

```
if (validateZipcode(form["zipcode"], document.getElementById("zipcode_help")))
```

And remember that (unlike form element names) id has to be unique.

EDIT: I just noticed that you already do what I've shown above in your `onblur=` handler, so apparently I'm not telling you anything you didn't already know.

For the html that you show, where the field and its associated help span have related ids, you may like to consider something like this:

```
function validateZipcode(inputField) {
    var help = document.getElementById(inputField.id + "_help");
    if (inputField.value === "") {
        help.innerHTML = "Please enter a number";
        return false;
    }
    help.innerHTML = "";
    return true;
}
function placeOrder(form) {
    if (validateZipcode(form["zipcode"])){
        alert("Submit");
    }
}
```

That is, just pass the field itself to the function, and then figure out from its id what the associated help field will be.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kY3BJ/

Comment: thanks for your answer! I think I can shorten my code with the way you showed me.